# How do you put Game Center Achievements into your iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, gamekit, achievements

I am very new to Xcode and Objective C. So I need help with the Game Center achievements. I have already set it up on the iTunes connect but don't know how to make them work in my game. 
Also, I want to make it so if the user presses a button they get an achievement on Game Center. I have done nothing so far with Gamekit except for import the framework.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a teacher.  If you want to learn how to do something, please read the documentation.  Apple provides copious amounts of documentation.  Read that, attempt to write the code, and if you have a *specific* problem that you cannot debug on your own, ask it on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has numerous videos and documentation you can look through to get this done...

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/gamecenter/

I don't recall the exact API call you will need but you can find it on the Apple developer portal.